# Help identifying an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, identification, remote-control

Attached you find a photo of an MCU. It is used in an remote controller of an home automation application. It is a low-power an low-cost product. I think the package is TSSOP30.

500T
1531XX00
  JAPAN

ist printed on the package.
Which MCU could it be?

[image]

Comment: Unlikely to be an mcu when its part of a remote, more likely a dedicated remote code chip. whats that black blob on top of it, cant you get rid of it?

Comment: Its probably a custom ASIC and you aren't going to find a datasheet for it. If you want to reverse engineer it, go for it.

Comment: 30 pins is very rare. It's unlikely to be anything off-the-shelf.

Comment: It is definitely a MCU, since it even has an attached EEPROM, likely with microcode.

Comment: @AliChen: not necessarily, there are a bunch of remote controller asics on the market that store code tables and configs in there

Comment: Maybe some Sony part particular to their IR protocol.

Comment: It's an 1k EEPROM connected via SPI.